# XCode Reference Type - Relative to Project

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.3

I need to set the reference type as relative to project in my xcode project when i add another project to it. The problem i am having is that i dont find the "Reference Type" command/tick box anywhere on the screen. I am using xcode 4.3.3 and maybe this has changed because in the tutorial i am using to create this project it simply says set the reference type relative to the project but i cannot do so. Any help greatly appreaciated. all i see is the following -

1. Copy Items to destinations group folder (if needed)
2. Create groups for any added folders
3. Create folder references for any added folders
4. Add targets to - "My projectname"

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option-click the file/directory in the navigator and choose **Show File Inspector**. Under the **Identity and Type** section you'll see **Location**. Change it there.

Comment: Go to View > Utilities > Show File Inspector    (the file inspector is the view on the right)